# Bootstrap popover does not toggle after changing its content

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

I have a row of `buttons` and on every `click` i want to fill the popover with data from an `ajax` call.

What i have done

```
   $(document).on('click','.foo', function (event){
   $(this).popover({
            html: true,
            trigger: 'manual',
            title:'Foo Title',
            placement: 'bottom',
            content: ''
}).popover('toggle');
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('id').substring(21);
    getResults(id);
});
```

Now i can toggle the popover and run the function which brings to me the desired data.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "get",
        success: function (response) {
           var $data = $(response);
           console.log($data);
           var data = $data;
           var popover = $('#foo' + id).attr('data-content',data).data('bs.popover');
           popover.setContent();
           popover.$tip.addClass(popover.options.placement);

        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("fail");
        }
    });
```

The popover opens correctly and the ajax data are appended correct. But the problem is that the popover stays opens and i cannot close it any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making the ajax call every time `.foo` is clicked regardless of whether or not the popover is supposed to toggle `show` or `hide`.

```
$(document).on('click', '.foo', function (event) {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.popover({
        html: true,
        trigger: 'manual',
        title:'Foo Title',
        placement: 'bottom',
        content: ''
    }).popover('toggle');

    event.preventDefault();

    $this.on('show.bs.popover', function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id').substring(21);
        getResults(id);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

JSFiddle with example. Replace data var with ajax returned data.
http://jsfiddle.net/1qgwn1Lu/

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="foo">Click to toggle popover</button>
```

jQuery: Attach event on 'show.bs.popover' [bootstrap popover event documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-events) then initiate popover.

```
var eNumber = 1;
    $('.foo').on('show.bs.popover', function () {
               //replace this data with ajax call.
               var data = 'ajaxCall#' + eNumber;
               var popover = $(this).attr('data-content',data).data('bs.popover');
               popover.setContent();
               popover.$tip.addClass(popover.options.placement);
               eNumber += 1;
    }).popover({html: true,
                trigger: 'click',
                title:'Foo Title',
                placement: 'bottom',
                content: ''})
```

If you assign the popover during the click event you are adding the handler over and over again. Only need to be initialized through the passed popover properties as trigger 'click'